# Adding a JMenuBar to a JFrame from another class

Tags: java, swing

I've created a class which holds a basic JFrame and another class which holds code for a JMenu but when I try to call the JMenu in the window class I am unable to use setJMenu(). I am not sure what I am missing can someone help?

#### Window.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class Window {
    JFrame frame;

    Menubar m = new Menubar();

    Window(){
        frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");

        frame.setJMenuBar(m);
        frame.setSize(200, 300);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

#### Menubar.java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Menubar {
    JMenuBar menubar;
    JMenu menu;
    JMenuItem item1;

    Menubar(){
        menubar = new JMenuBar();
        menu = new JMenu("File");
        item1 = new JMenuItem("item");

        menubar.add(menu);
        menu.add(item1);
        
    }
}
```

VS Code tells me to use getJMenu which also does not work.

Comment: don't name custom classes the same as framework classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simply that you are not exposing the JMenuBar in MenuBar

Rather than your `MenuBar()` constructor, add this

```
public static JMenuBar createMenuBar(){
    menubar = new JMenuBar();
    menu = new JMenu("File");
    item1 = new JMenuItem("item");

    menubar.add(menu);
    menu.add(item1);
    return menu;
}
```

And in Window

```
Window(){
    frame = new JFrame("Test Frame");
    frame.setJMenuBar(MenuBar.createMenuBar());
```

Of course the problem then is that you don't have an `Action` added to the JMenuItem in your menu bar, which is why it is often better to build the entire GUI in one class... unless you also add API to do things like set the button's Action through a method in `Window`

Comment: So is there no way to add actions to the items in the menubar class? Say I want to just print "hello" to console and used `if(e.getSource() == item1){System.out.println("Hello");} `within the actionPerformed method. Would this not be possible? @ControlAltDel

Comment: "So is there no way" there is a way: You can go through the JMenuBar hierarchy and find the JMenuItem. But in general this is a pain in the a$$ and generally indicates bad design

Comment: Yeah, it is kinda a sucky way of making it work and probably would be better just doing it all in one class like you mentioned. Thanks for the help it's appreciated

Comment: "So is there no way" What you can do is add an `Action` parameter to the createMenuBar method, and so the action for the button can get passed into the method. The other thing you can also do is to create a generic response - create an ActionListener in MenuBar where it calls firePropertyChange (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#firePropertyChange-java.lang.String-boolean-boolean-), then list this functionality in your documentation